# R shiny app not running on host and asking to open in browser

Tags: r, shiny, localhost

I am using R-Studio for R shiny app, I have created two files one is ui.R and the other is server.R.

ui.R cosist of following code:

```
# install.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)
# runExample("01_hello")
fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("This is the title Panel"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("This is Sidebar Panel"),
    mainPanel("This is the main Panel")
    
  )
)
```

and server.R consists of the following code:

```
function(input,output){
  
}
```

And they both are in the same directory, now when I am running the application, it is showing me the below picture in R studio host and asking me to open it in the browser, I want to open the R studio host only as well as when I click to open in browser then open in the browser.

[image]

Comment: If you are using the latest version of RStudio, then there's a bug which causes a blank shiny window but opens correctly in browser. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12649

Comment: okay, is there any way by which we can solve this problem?

Comment: either wait for RStudio to push a fix or revert to old version of RStudio, or use external browser. Next to Run App button, there is an option to set that shiny app should by default open in browser instead of internal window